# Can't Get Susy Version 2 to work

Tags: phpstorm, compass, susy

I've started using Susy 2 with my Rails projects and now I want use it with a php project. I just installed sass-3.4.11, compass-1.0.3 and susy-2.2.2 using rbenv to control my environment. I imported compass and susy at the start of my scss file chain:

```
@import "compass";
@import "susy";
```

I pasted the following code from my working ruby project in my php one:

```
$susy: (
  container: $page-width,
  columns: 12,
  gutters: 1em/3.5em,  //$gutter-width / $column-width,
  column-width: 3.5em,
  global-box-sizing: border-box
);

@include border-box-sizing; // Part of Susy
```

The compiler flags container, columns, etc. as errors. It's with border-box-sizing, establish-baseline, and span(12 of 12). The $susy: () is part of the version 2 is it not? Is there something else I have to do in a php project to get it to work? I do have busy version 1 working in another php project.

In case it makes any difference this is my compile statement:

```
compass compile /volumes/data/htdocs/zetcho
```

I'm using the PHPStorm IDE to invoke it.

## Update

It may be the IDE, PHPStorm, that is the issue. It's flagging the statement as being in error, but the compiler isn't complaining. I'm have way through refactoring the site and it's a mess so I don't know if Susy is working or not. I also use RubyMine, which is another JetBrains IDE. It doesn't complain about the code.

## Update 2

If I uncomment the $susy: code, the IDE won't run the compiler. Specifically, it doesn't like the colons after container, columns, etc.

## Update 3

I finished refactoring the site with problem statement commented out. It looks to by laid out just fine. I do have a couple of pre-version 2 variables defined.

Comment: what PHPStorm version do you work with? NB: to have the compiler triggered for your  code, make sure to enable 'Trigger watcher regardless of syntax errors' option in your Compass file watcher settings

Answer (score 0):

It turned out I was using version 2 of Susy all along. The problem was that the version of PHPStorm I was using incorrectly flagged the code as an error. When I upgraded from 7.1.3 to 8.0.3, the code parsed correctly.